# Factory Pattern in C++: generating explicit createInstance()-Method automatically

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, createinstance, dlsym

i have the problem in writing a C++ framework, that users should have less overhead than possible to use it. Users can publish their work to the frameworks by creating a shared library that contains a class, which is derived by a frameworks' BaseClass and implementing an extern "C" createInstance()-method in order to return an instance its' derived class. So the framework can access the user class by calling the createInstance-Method through the shared library with dlsym().

```
class BaseClass{}
class UserClass : public BaseClass{}

extern "C"{  
   BaseClass* UserXcreateInstance(){
    return new UserClass();
   }                        
}
```

In framework:

```
typedef BaseClass* (*CreateInstance) ();
void* handle;
CreateInstance createInstance;
handle = dlopen( "libUserLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL );
createInstance = reinterpret_cast <CreateInstance*> dlsym( handle, "UserXcreateInstance" );
BaseClass* userX = createInstance();
```

My Question: Is it possible to generate the UserXcreateInstance()-method, which is redundant in each user library, so that the user don`t have to think about it?

I thought it would be possible with templates+macros, but I haven't yet found a way to do this...

Another approach, I was thinking is directly call the constructor of any user class via dlsym and appropiate name mangling. (I know any namespace + class name from a config file) But I don`t think this a proper solution, especially a constructor call is not the same as a regular function call... but very interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine a way to create this automatically without any coding per part of the user. I can imagine ways to simplify it, perhaps using a macro:

```
#define OBJECT_CREATOR(X) \
    extern "C" {          \
         BaseClass *UserXCreateInstance() {\
             return new X(); \
         }\
    }
```

And the user just need to put on his cpp file:

```
OBJECT_CREATOR(UserClass);
```

Comment: Thank you, one line is better than four ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume calling the user function via `dlsym` is not an absolute requirement.

What you want is easy to achieve by using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). A constructor of a static helper object then registers relevant data in a central repository. It should go like this:

```
template <typename UserClass>
class BaseClass
{
  private:
    class UserObjectFactory
    {
      UserObjectFactory()
      {
        std::string myname = typeid(UserClass).name();
        CentralObjectFactory::instance()->register(this, myname);
      }
      BaseClass* XUserCreateInstance()
      {
        return new UserClass;
      }            
    };
    static UserObjectFactory factory; 
};
```

Users code is simple:

```
class MyClass : public BaseClass<MyClass>
{
  // whatever
};
```

Presumably, the `CentralObjectFactory` instance contains some kind of (multi)map from `std::string` to `UserObjectFactory`.

`myname` could be initialized to some uniquely generated string instead of `typeid(UserClass).name()`, in order to avoid collisions.

If all you need is a single object of each user's class, you can make `UserObjectFactory` create an instance of `UserClass` and register it instead.

```
   std::string myname = typeid(UserClass).name();
   CentralObjectRepository::instance()->register(XUserCreateInstance(), myname);
```

Does this design fulfil your needs?

Comment: Your idea sounds very interesting, but it doesn`t work for me. The constructor of the static helper class is not achieved... Should this happen by the dlopen-call of the users' shared library or are there more preconditions?

Comment: Uh-oh, I'm terribly sorry, this indeed doesn't work. I'll let you know if I can fix it.