# How can I autoregister c++ objects with a factory when those objects are in separate shared librariies?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, registration, factory

The situation I have is that I would like to create a library which contains a factory, lets call it FooFactory, for derived classes from a common base class, I’ll call that IFoo. I then have a variety of objects Foo1, Foo2, etc which are derived from IFoo, but which are declared in separate shared libraries.

When Foo1, Foo2, etc are in the same library, I can define static global objects InitializeFoo1, InitializeFoo2, etc which, in their constructors, register a create method for that class with the factory. However, when they are in separate libraries these initializer objects are never instantiated and so the derived classes are never registered.

My previous research suggests that if these libraries were statically linked the, otherwise never used, initializers might be pruned away and their constructors never called, but is this the case for shared libraries as well? If so, is there some way to insure that these initializer objects are instantiated? Finally, if I am just "going about this all wrong", I am of course open to any advice on a better way to proceed.

I should also note that this question appears en passant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581998/factory-pattern-in-c-generating-explicit-createinstance-method-automaticall). In that case, a proposed answer to the original question suggests such static initializer object, but the questioner comments that it does not work for the reason for the same reason I have - that the initializer is never instantiated - but this comment essentially goes unaddressed.

Some context: this is all happening on a Linux machine, I am compiling with gcc 4.7.3. In case it helps at all, the reason for doing all of this is to allow developers to create new derived objects and which can be linked into the code without modification or recompilation of the existing code base. (The new objects are created based on run-time events.)

Comment: Not clear what you want. A factory is an object/function that creates instances of a class (1 or more). Being a factory allows the factory to register all the objects it created.

Comment: What's wrong with manually calling a `register()` method from every new shared object loaded?

Comment: @DmitryMarkin in my context it does not make sense to do this because I do not know the identities of the objects when I link to them.

Comment: @egur I do not quite understand what you are saying. My understanding of a factory is that if the objects to be created are not known to the factory at compile time, they need a method to register themselves with the factory so that it will know how to create them. Do you have something different in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the case you describe on RHEL 5.7 with gcc 4.1.2 and the global static gets constructed also when defined in a shared library. If the main is linked with the shared library with the `g++ -l lib` option than the constructor gets called before the `main()` as expected, and if the lib is loaded manually using the `dlopen()` call then naturally it is constructed when the lib is loaded. But it is constructed automatically in both cases.

Anyway, perhaps as a workaround you can define a "constructor" for the shared library, i.e. a function that is called by the system when the library is loaded, and define you initializing object as a static within the function? The syntax for this is as follows:

```
extern "C" {

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) libload(void)
{
    cout << "dll ctor called\n";
    static A a;
}

void __attribute__ ((destructor)) libunload(void)
{
}

} // extern
```

Comment: WRT the first half of your comment, I simply do not get this result. I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and gcc 4.7.3. I tried also loading with dlopen() and I get the same result (i.e. object is not instantiated). Can you (or anyone) suggest how I could go about debugging this?<p>if it helps, when I run nm on the .so library, I get output like the following: (though I do not yet understand this output fully).<p>
000000000001b7b8 W _ZN3mlx16NodeAutoRegisterINS_7NodeXXEEC1Ev<p>
000000000001b7b8 W _ZN3mlx16NodeAutoRegisterINS_7NodeXXEEC2Ev<p>Is it correct that this means the symbols are

Comment: Is it correct that the above means they symbols are in fact in the library (sorry, i am new to the formatting skills of Stackoverflow comments)

Comment: re debugging you could set a breakpoint in the ctor, accept gdb's suggestion to make it pending on the library load and see if you get there when the lib is loaded.